# Machine learning algorithms for tabular dataset

Tags: neural-network, classification, convolutional-neural-network, binary-classification

I have a dataset with 120 features and 5000 instances. The dataset is combination of categorical and numerical values. It is a tabular dataset. My problem is a binary classification problem. I trained my dataset with all classic classification algorithms like Naive Bayes, Bayesian net, SVM, MLP, Random forest, Logistic regression etc. I would like to know is there any algorithms available in the machine learning field which is new and not the classic one and can be implemented using a tabular dataset.

I heard about Convolution neural network, deep neural network etc but I believe they are used in image data not tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Generalized Additive Models (GAM). It models the response variable, $y$, as a sum of functions of individual features $f_i(x_i)$: $y = \sum\limits_if_i(x_i)$. You don't need to provide $f_i$, the algorithm finds learns them from the data. By analyzing the $f_i$, you can see, which feature contributes significantly, and in which way. You can even fit the $f_i$ to simple analytic functions and get an analytic dependence of $y$ on $x_i$.

Links for GAM: [GAM in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model), [GAM in R](https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/), [GAM in Python](https://codeburst.io/pygam-getting-started-with-generalized-additive-models-in-python-457df5b4705f),
[ClassificationGAM in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationgam.html), as well as [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/tag/gam/), [here](https://environmentalcomputing.net/statistics/gams/), [here](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/07/30/gam/), and [here](https://datascienceplus.com/generalized-additive-models/).

A related method is Alternating Conditional Expectations (ACE) from this paper: [link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1985.10478157). I wrote a blog post about it [here](https://vladgladkikh.wordpress.com/2019/01/21/learning-parametric-relationships-from-data-using-ace/).

These methods are not new, but I have a feeling that you didn't try them.

I also recommend browsing through methods in weka. It has some interesting, non-mainstream algorithms, such as [classifier for learning functional trees](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/functionalTrees/index.html), [HotSpot](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/hotSpot/index.html), [alternating model trees](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/alternatingModelTrees/index.html), [alternating decision trees](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/alternatingDecisionTrees/index.html), and many other.